# How to build highly available topic subscribers

Tags: docker, architecture, kubernetes, activemq-classic

I am looking for solutions how we can build a highly available AMQ Topic subscribers.

Scenario: Given that I have an AMQ broker with failover nodes, and I have two services subscribed to Topic 1 and Topic 2 respectively. Is there a easy way to make each subscribers redundant? Something like active/passive subscribers? Than when an instance failed, system will continue to work though at reduced throughput?

I am looking if Docker Swarm can do this but it doesn't seem to be fitting as its best suited for microservices receiving web requests.

Solutions I have considered:

1. Setup VM vSphere with HA where I have two nodes hosting 1 TopicSubscriber. This is ridiculously expensive setup IMO.
2. Deploy as container in docker swarm with replica = 3. Each message needs to be validated by each instance if the event has already been processed by the other nodes.
3. Find a leader-election way like Zookeper. Sounds like a lot of work and plumbing.

[image]
Appreciate your input. Is this possible with Docker Swarm or Kubernetes?
TIA/RD.

Comment: You are asking for an opinion, which is off-topic on SO.  My opinion: Kubernetes

Comment: Instead of solving this problem with infrastructure you might be able to solve it with the broker itself. ActiveMQ 5.x (and ActiveMQ Artemis) has the idea of "exclusive" consumers (i.e. multiple consumers are connected but only 1 is allowed to actually get the messages; if the chosen consumer fails/disconnects the broker will auto failover and choose another consumer).  I'm not sure if this will work with ActiveMQ 5.x & topic subscribers (since 5.x doesn't implement JMS 2.0 with shared subscriptions), but if you have issues you could try moving to ActiveMQ Artemis which does implement JMS 2.0.